# Unable to insert data in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

Could you please help to resolve the below error -

> INSERT blocks,color=blue number=90 1547095860
>   ERR: {"error":"partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=1"}

Note - 1547095860 is - 1/10/2019, 10:21:00 AM Standard Time

I am trying to insert this data on today i.e. 25th jan 2019.

MY DB settings are as in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAMc9.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Try `INSERT blocks,color=blue number=90 1547095860000000000` Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry Samuel. Still the same error. I am not sure what exactly am I missing.

Comment: Which database are you on? `LINSERVER` or `test_db`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the screenshot provided, I suppose you're attempting to insert data into one of the databases named `LINSERVER`?

By default, if no `retention policy` (RP) is specified for a database then the system will go with the `autogen` RP; which has an **infinite** retention period. In other words, you can insert data anywhere from the start of `epoch` time till the end and data will be preserved .

If a retention policy of example `7d` is defined for a database, this means that you can only insert data for a limited period of one week. Data point who falls outside the scope the `retention period` is considered as `expired` and will be "garbage collected" by the database.

This also means that you cannot `backfill` data outside the retention period. My guess is `database` could have a relatively small retention period which resulted in the new `data` that you just inserted to be considered as `expired`. Henceforth the error message ***"points beyond retention policy dropped=1"***

**Solution**: Either use the default `autogen` RP or make the duration of your `database` retention policy longer. All depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this is using the epoch time in seconds. It needs to be in nanoseconds, basically add 9 zeros to the end of your number.